# AspectJ not working with Maven in my webapp (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, web-services, maven-2, aspectj

I have a Webservice Maven project running on Websphere 8.0 and im trying to implement AOP with Aspectj in it without any result.

The aspect class definition its ok (I can tell because its the same in every example I see) and as I can tell the pom its good too. I will add the code to be sure :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.5</source>
                            <target>1.5</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

So when I consume a service with the method annotation nothing happens, no error no log no nothing! I dont know if its not weaving the project or what its going on.

If u guys need more info let me know!

Answer (score 0):

If your aspect definitions are in another project, then you need to include them into the project that is using them as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Note: change spring-aspects to your project artefact